# Find words in long string in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to find an efficient way to look for words that I have in a file and then compare to a long string line with no spaces to look for these words:

```
Example:
FileOfWords.txt
  THE
  HOUSE
  DOG
  ON
  LINE

  string1 = " ASASASASASATHEHFGFDFGDFDFDDOGFDFDF"
  string2 = "DOGLINEJSDKJSDJKSDKJSDTHECVCVVCV"
  string3 = "UHFDUIHKDFSHUIDSFUIHDSFHUSDSHUIS"

  compare words in FileOfWords.txt to string

  Output:
  Words in string1 found: THE, DOG
  Words in string2 found: DOG, LINE
  Words in string3 found:
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: You're right I should have but Alessiox has posted the function i was looking for. I'll do so in the future though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An easy way of doing this is simple as

- read the file
- word by word check if that word is `in` the larger strings

That is,

```
with open(fname) as f:
    wrds = f.read().strip().split('\n')

mtches = [[] for x in range(3)]

for w in wrds:
    if w in string1: mtches[0].append(w)
    if w in string2: mtches[1].append(w)
    if w in string3: mtches[2].append(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive way to do this is using a bruteforce approach, that is looking for every substring (k-mer) of length *k* (where *k* goes from 1 to the length of the string itself) and check if such substring is in your file.

First thing to do is to define a function (generator) that returns every possible k-mer:

```
def all_kmers(sequence, k):
    for i in range(len(sequence) - k + 1):
        yield sequence[i:i + k]
```

Now it is time to import the file and your three strings:

```
# open the file, import its lines thanks to readlines() and then close it
fileIN=open('FileOfWords.txt','r')
myWords=fileIN.readlines()
fileIN.close()

# remove newline tags
for id in range(len(myWords)):
    myWords[id]=myWords[id].strip()

# load the strings
string1 = " ASASASASASATHEHFGFDFGDFDFDDOGFDFDF"
string2 = "DOGLINEJSDKJSDJKSDKJSDTHECVCVVCV"
string3 = "UHFDUIHKDFSHUIDSFUIHDSFHUSDSHUIS"
```

And now it's time to rock:

```
print "In string 1:"
for k in range(len(string1)):
    for kmer in all_kmers(string1, k):
        if kmer in myWords:
            print kmer

print "\nIn string 2:"
for k in range(len(string2)):
    for kmer in all_kmers(string2, k):
        if kmer in myWords:
            print kmer

print "\nIn string 3:"
for k in range(len(string3)):
    for kmer in all_kmers(string3, k):
        if kmer in myWords:
            print kmer
```

Such code returns:

```
In string 1:
THE
DOG

In string 2:
DOG
THE
LINE

In string 3:
```

*Note*: by enclosing the three strings in a list you can avoid 3 separate steps and enclose everything in a unique loop that runs through such list.
So basically after the string(s) definition, the code is:

```
myList=[string1,string2,string3]

for l in range(len(myList)):
    StringUnderTest=myList[l]
    print "String #"+str(l+1)
    for k in range(len(StringUnderTest)):
        for kmer in all_kmers(StringUnderTest, k):
            if kmer in myWords:
                print kmer
    print
```

And such code returns

```
String #1
THE
DOG

String #2
DOG
THE
LINE

String #3
```

Comment: Thank you Alessiox the all_kmers function is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Mind though that this is not a "standard" function, is a generator. As you can see I iterate with the for loops over the results generated by `all_kmers`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to load the strings into a list.  And search using two nested loops:

```
strings = [" ASASASASASATHEHFGFDFGDFDFDDOGFDFDF","DOGLINEJSDKJSDJKSDKJSDTHECVCVVCV","UHFDUIHKDFSHUIDSFUIHDSFHUSDSHUIS"]

words = ['THE','HOUSE','DOG','ON','LINE']


for i,string in enumerate(strings):
    result = "Words in String{0} found: ".format(i+1)
    for word in words:
        idx = string.find(word)
        if idx != -1:
            result += word +', '

    print(result[:-2])
```

or load the Words from the text file as per @guiscri 's answer